# Google Cloud Run automatically redirecting to "https"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Google Cloud Run app. I need it to support both "http://" and "https://" requests on a custom domain (for legacy reasons). But it seems all http requests are automatically redirected to https. (A Redirect with status 302 is sent.) The redirect response include the header "Server: Google Frontend" which, if I understand correctly, suggest the redirect happen in some frontend before the request hit my application.

Does cloud run mandate https, or is there is configuration somewhere to allow both schemes?

(I understand that Cloud Run internally proxies all requests to the container as http on port 8080, regardless of scheme/port of the external url. My question is if it is possible to have external requests as http.)

Comment: @Pentium10: No, that answer explains that Cloud Run internally proxies all requests to the container as http even if the request url is https. My question is if Cloud Run can serve http requests without redirecting them to https.

Comment: Short answer: No. Only https is possible, be design.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: OK thank you. Do you know if this have changed? Because there are some articles that indicate otherwise, e.g. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-https-part-1/ which is what confused me.

Comment: Have a try on it. I just tested and I got a 302. The  article of my friend John as been released just after the official announcement of Cloud Run in Beta. A lot of improvement, and a go to GA, have been performed, and the article is now out of date.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: OK thank you. If you want some karma, post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Run only supports `https`. `http` request will receive a 302 to the `https` endpoint.

Comment: At the moment of writing, it seems a http request will return a 404.

Comment: This is incorrect. I just tested, a 302 is returned. Please capture an example where you got a 404.

Comment: there can be a slight delay after changes/setup, based on my experience earlier today where the 404 resolved to redirect http to https after about an hour (not sure exactly how long)--it does work without additional setup in my experience